# How to uncompress ".tar" type files in windows CMD?

Tags: windows, cmd

How to uncompress files type with *.tar in windows by command?
I need install any uncompress tools?

Comment: This is not a site where other people search the internet for you! Please go through these help articles: [ask], [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My environment with Windows 10 (Version 1803 build SO 17134.407) has `tar`, I do not know wheter is standard or because I have Visual Studio installed. See [Tar and Curl Come to Windows!](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/virtualization/2017/12/19/tar-and-curl-come-to-windows/)

Comment: The usage of windows 10 tar command (btw similar to linux syntax) `tar -xvzf C:\PATH\TO\FILE\FILE-NAME.tar.gz -C C:\PATH\TO\FOLDER\EXTRACTION`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract the contents of a *.tar file then just use 7zip or winRAR, these two applications are readily available on the internet, 
But if you want to do the same operation on command prompt then open the folder where the winRAR or 7zip is installed(c:\Program Files\winRAR), there you will get a "rar.exe" files which u can easily open in the command prompt or set it as one of your environment variables and mount it in the command prompt and extract the *.tar file. If you are finding trouble with extracting then just type "help rar" a full list of available commands and switches will populate. Windows already have a inbuilt command line compressor "compact" but that won't work, therefore this is the only option.

Comment: Are you sure this is the only option? Doesn't `tar.exe`, as suggested by Alessandro, work?

Comment: It's one of options. And i kown what does he mean.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand if your os have tar.exe then directly you can do it.